# Distribution and periodic update of a web application

Tags: java, postgresql, server

I have been asked to develop a web based application which would be locally deployed at multiple (>100) geographical locations. Till now, I have been designing web applications which are deployed at a cloud and accessed by clients across the globe. In this particular project, the client wants to maintain there own local servers since they cannot ensure continous Internet connectivity. These local deployments may periodically synchronize data with the central datacenter.

Now, I am pondering if it is possible to provide a packaged solution for deploying the complete stack of our web application, so that a technical person at the client end can just download it on the linux box and the packaged solution configures everything  (including application server, database, schemas). Additionally, I should also be able to push periodic updates for code etc.

I had a look at [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), but I am not sure if it is able to fulfill all these requirements or if there is a standard protocol/solution for this which I can build upon.

My web application stack includes

- Postgres
- JBoss
- Class files etc.
- JDK
- Other dependencies for these softwares.

Comment: What do you think Docker is lacking specifically?

Comment: Is it possible to push incremental updates to application code (JSP , class files etc) ?. In such cases the server is needed to be restarted. Since the client is completely non technical, I wanted to automate this task as well or manage this remotely.